# Prevent webmasters from removing injected html elements

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-extension

I want to create web browser extension (Opera, Chrome, Firefox) that will inject html elements (iframe) into webpage. Is there any way to prevent webmasters from removing html that I've injected with javascript.

Comment: No because it would be done client side....The same way you can use Greasemonkey to change the CSS of the site....the changes will be local to you only.

Comment: I dont like the smell of this question :(

Comment: Please show us the current plugin code and how webmasters do remove the html it injects.